# Making most of time in haram shareef

Tags: salat-qada, umrah

I am currently visiting haram Mecca and I am not much familiar with namaz expect from fard and sunnat. I have heard that it is good to pray nafal prayers.

I have lost a lot of prayers since my teenage till now. I have pain in my foot and it has flared up since my first umrah.

I feel sad I cannot do much. How can I make most of my few days here.

Answer (score 1):

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. With regards to praying when you pain then you can sit down and pray.

Furthermore, there is the greatest act of worship outside of Fard (obligatory actions) you may do and that is the remembrance of ALLAAH. And highest remembrance is reading the Quraan with understanding and if not then just reading the Quraan.

If you cannot read the Quraan then doing dhikr at all times.

> Abu Darda reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Shall I not tell you of the best of your deeds, which is the purest to your KING, which raises you among your ranks, which is better for you than spending gold and money in charity, and which is better for you than meeting your enemy and striking the necks of each other?” They said, “Of course!” The Prophet said, “It is the remembrance of ALLAAH ALMIGHTY.” Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 3377

> Samurah ibn Jundab reported: The Messenger of ALLAAH, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “The most beloved words to ALLAAH are four: glory be to ALLAAH, praise be to ALLAAH, there is no god but ALLAAH, and ALLAAH is the greatest. There is no harm in starting with any of them.” Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2137

[image]